# Arduino uno, 2x parallax continous servos (BOE), wifi shield power draw

Tags: arduino-uno, power, wifi, servo

I am unable to properly connect those things together with batteries:

```
Arduino Uno
Parallax continuous servo
Arduino wifi shield
```

5xAA batteries are connected through power jack to arduino which I assumed would power both arduino and the wifi shield and then I have 1 9 volt battery to power 2 servo motors.

With this setup it seems like I can only get to run 1 servo at a time.

Here is a picture how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mGKe.jpg

I'm really desperate for any advice/guidance when it comes to powering this thing.

Comment: 9v is too high for servos and risks destroying them. 5x AA is not enough for an Arduino's input except when they are new.

Answer (score 1):

9V batteries can only supply  very little current. So two servo's is too much.

Just use another set of multiple AA batteries for the servo's.